# Overload/specialize global operator initially declared with templated rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, function-templates, forwarding-reference

Let’s say we have global operator defined in a library (all in global namespace)

```
template< class tAnyType >
SpecialStream & operator << ( SpecialStream & os, tAnyType && value )
{
    return os.serialize( std::forward<tAnyType>( value ) );
}
```

That I’d like to overload/specialize (which one is it?) for one of my class, such as:

```
SpecialStream & operator << ( SpecialStream & os, const MyClass & value )
{
    return os << value.i << value.s.c_str();
}
```

I'd like ONE operator overload that would work with const/non-const lvalues as well as rvalues, just like the one in the library does.

As it turns out, I have to make at least three of them :

- "MyClass &"  to capture non-const lvalues
- "const MyClass &" to capture const lvalues
- "MyClass &&" to capture rvalues

That just doesn't seem right to have to write three overloads for each class specializatoin. Shouldn't I be able to capture everything with "const MyClass &" (as we see everywhere in "stream" classes overloading <<), or with "MyClass &&" (supposed to be able to capture everything)?

Here's an attemp (that doesn't compile) at using a single operator taking a 'const MyClass &', that ought to be just fine for any kind of argument:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------
// Radically simplified code from a library, in global namespace 

class SpecialStream
{
public:
    template< class tAnyType >
    SpecialStream & serialize( tAnyType && value )
    {
        cout << value;  // whatever, just an example         <-- line 13
        return *this;
    }
};

// global operator that I’d like to overload/specialize for a specific class
template< class tAnyType >
SpecialStream & operator << ( SpecialStream & os, tAnyType && value )
{
    return os.serialize( forward<tAnyType>( value ) );    // <-- line 22
}
//---------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------
// code from my project 
class MyClass
{
public:
    int i;
    string s;
};

// Global operator overload/specialization (does not work! See question below)
// Tried const MyClass &, Myclass &&, MyClass
SpecialStream & operator << ( SpecialStream & os, const MyClass & value )
{
    return os << value.i << value.s.c_str();
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    SpecialStream oss;
    MyClass     object;
    oss << object;          // compiler error!             <-- line 46
}
```

The above does not compile since on oss << object, the compiler always tries to use the template operator from the library, not mine. I’m using Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) which I assume is OK with this part of C++11. Compiler error is:

```
1>test.cpp(13): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'MyClass' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Followed by the very long list of all binary operator << the compiler has tried such as:

```
note: could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(const void *)'
```

then finally (we see the problem is that it tries to instanciate line 22 instead of using my operator):

```
1>  test.cpp(13): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, MyClass)'
1>  test.cpp(22): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'SpecialStream &SpecialStream::serialize<MyClass&>(tAnyType)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              tAnyType=MyClass &
1>          ]
1>  test.cpp(46): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'SpecialStream &operator <<<MyClass&>(SpecialStream &,tAnyType)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              tAnyType=MyClass &
1>          ]
```

Whether the library code is good or bad design could be a question, but that’s not what I’m asking right now. As I said, copying my operator to take a (non-const) MyClass & works fine, but I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to duplicate code (SpecialStream does it all with a single operator after all).

Is there any way to do it in a single function?

Comment: Why would an `operator <<` take a forwarding reference instead of by const-ref to begin with? If it took `(SpecialStream&, tAnyType const&)` instead, as is idiomatic, this wouldn't be an issue...